# How do I test if user is redirected to the current page after social auth?

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-socialite

I want to make user stay on the same page after authenticating using Facebook, for instance. But when testing there's no notion of current page, as far as I could tell. I could probably set `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but is that really okay? And if using `selenium`, that would most likely require quite an effort to make it work. And not sure, if that's okay to allow tests to access external resources.

Comment: I would just save their auth sate in the `$_SESSION` super global. Actually laravel socialite already does that for you depending on how you have the session driver configured. That is, unless you are using the stateless authentication option.

Comment: Be that as it may, how do I test that?

Comment: Also, I tried doing `return redirect()->intended()` instead of `return redirect('/')` in facebook callback, but it redirected to main page anyway, so you seem to be wrong.

Comment: Facebook is going to redirect you to whatever callback page you set as the callback URL. Set the correct callback URL in Facebook developer console then after handling the auth state in Laravel you have to add the correct route name as defined in your router file `return redirect()->intended('YOUR_CORRECT_ROUTE_NAME')`. Returning an empty function call with no args isn't going to work.

Comment: How is it that it isn't going to work? `RedirectResponse intended(string $default = '/', int $status = 302, array $headers = array(), bool $secure = null)`